# Inno Setup Create more icons on Start menu (Win10)

Tags: inno-setup

I've read various answers here about how to manage the `[Icons]` section of Inno Setup but I haven't found anything about creating more than an icon calling the same exe.

What I need is to put in my users startup menu (under my program folder) 2 different parameterized calls to my exe file:

I write an example to better explain:

```
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters: "-config"; IconFile"{app}\{#MyConfigIcon}
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
```

What I expect from the code above is that in my windows 10 startmenu, under a folder with my company name there are 3 shortcuts, one to the normal exe, another to the same exe file with a parameter that starts the configuration procedure and a different icon the third is the uninstall shortcut.

What I find in the start menu is Just the second shortcut (the parameterized one) while the first is not there. I presume the problem can be that 2 calls to the same exe can't be set on the start menu, so if somebody has a workaround for this it will be very appreciated.

Thank you In advance.

Comment: Have you tried manually creating these shorcuts yourself? I am not sure you can duplicate the same shortcut twice, which is what it ammounts to, even if the parameters are not the same. If you can manually do it then it can be done with Inno Setup.

Comment: You might have to change the `Name`  of one.

Comment: I don't understand why this was marked as duplicate. The other question is about an uninstall icon. My Start Menu has more than one item in the menu: https://imgur.com/a/phDf0 I see no issues here.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I assume that your two start menu entries point to a different binary (32-bit vs. 64-bit), while OP's entries point to the same binary + It's still true that using Start menu groups is a violation of Windows guidelines and even more so is adding an uninstall icon to the Start menu. So a whole question is kind of pointless anyway.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl OK. Kinda weord if you ask me. My other application has several sample files and they are all in the Start Menu. No one has ever complained. I am surprised that by default Inno Setup doesn;t apply a flag so that icons are only for pre Win 8. But then again, programs like AutoCAD 2018 put several shortcuts there. And yes, my two links are to the two bit editions.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, unfortunately InnoSetup does not allow more than one definition calling the same file, and if you do that it retains the last one. I presume it is a limit of the software and it's a pity, because I have a couple of calls with arguments that I use to start the application going to the configuration or I can use for other purposes. I'm not sure it is possible to define an entirely custom shortcut to do the job . And so to say, these work perfectly also in the windows 10 start menu.